# Deserializing xml with different declaration

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to deserialize following XML into an object in`C#`

the XML:

```
<rdlt version="1.5" xmlns:rdlt="http://www.rdlt.org" xmlns="http://www.rdlt.org">
    <created>2016-02-18T15:36:29.326+00:00</created>
    <updated>2016-02-18T15:36:29.326+00:00</updated>
</rdlt>
```

The object:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.rdml.org")]
public class Container
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.rdml.org")]
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.rdml.org")]
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialization:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\tmp\test.xml");
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Container));
var object = serializer.ReadObject(reader);
```

I get the following error that the elements and schema's do not match:

```
 Additional information: Error in line 1 position 2. Expecting element  
'Container' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication1'.. 
Encountered 'Element'  with name 'rdlt', namespace 'http://www.rdlt.org'.
```

Allready tried

- Adding the rdlt name to the root
- reader.MoveToContent();
- XmlReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... this code uses XmlSerializer.....

Usings.....

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Classes.....

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rdlt", Namespace = "http://www.rdlt.org")]
public class Container
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "created", Namespace = "http://www.rdlt.org")]
    public string Created { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "updated", Namespace = "http://www.rdlt.org")]
    public string Updated { get; set; }
}
```

Code.....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strXML = File.ReadAllText("xml.xml");
        byte[] bufXML = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(bufXML);

        // Deserialize to object
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));
        try
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ms1))
            {
                Container deserializedXML = (Container)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            }// put a break point here and mouse-over deserializedXML ….
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Your XML

```
<rdlt version="1.5" xmlns:rdlt="http://www.rdlt.org" xmlns="http://www.rdlt.org">
    <created>2016-02-18T15:36:29.326+00:00</created>
    <updated>2016-02-18T15:36:29.326+00:00</updated>
</rdlt>
```

I am reading your XML in to a string from a file in the application build folder called xml.xml... you will need to get the XML string from somewhere else or create the xml.xml file and save your XML for the code above to work

Comment: actually parsed it manually with an XML reader. Was a better fit to the issue

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- `object` is not valid name for local variable (please make sure to use real code next time), it could be `@object`;
- valid xml begins with `?xml` tag (e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`);
- `version` is a part of `?xml`, if you want *xml attribute* `version="1.5"` in root element, then you are in trouble;

If you have to deserialize that exact `xml`, then your only option is manual deserialization, e.g. using linq-to-xml:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\tmp\test.xml");
string version = xml.Root.Attribute("version").Value;
string space = "http://www.rdlt.org";
var obj = new Container()
{
    created = DateTime.Parse(xml.Root.Element(XName.Get("created", space)).Value),
    updated = DateTime.Parse(xml.Root.Element(XName.Get("updated", space)).Value),
};
```

---

If you omit `version` and can add `?xml` tag, then `DataSerializer` should work.

E.g. this *valid* xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdlt xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.rdml.org">
    <created>0001-01-01T00:00:00</created>
    <updated>0001-01-01T00:00:00</updated>
</rdlt>
```

Can be deserialized using:

```
[DataContract(Name = "rdlt", Namespace = "http://www.rdml.org")]
public class Container
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
}

// deserialize (using your code!)
var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\tmp\test.xml");
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Container));
var obj = serializer.ReadObject(reader);
```